# Decide if a function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: solution-verification, riemann-integration

I have the following function: $f:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow [-\pi,\pi]\ \  f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{xy}{x^4+y^2}, & (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
 0,& (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.$
 I need to decide if the function is or it is not Riemann Integrable. 
 I am trying to do this by proving that the function is continuous. If it is it means that is Riemann Integrable too. And it is not because I found two paths for which the approach is different. The two paths are:  $x = 0$ and $x = y$. Because of this, the function is not continuous and therefore is not Riemann Integrable, right? 
 I am not sure if this is the correct answare so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of this, the function is not continuous and therefore is not Riemann Integrable, right?

Not right. A discontinuous function can still Riemann integrable. For example, consider the function $f:[-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \neq 0\\0 & x = 0\end{cases}.$$
This function is discontinuous at $0$ but still Riemann integrable on $[-1, 1]$.

Even in your question, the function is only discontinuous at one point and so, that would not matter.

---

However, your function still is ***not*** Riemann integrable. This is because your function is not bounded. To see this, let $x = 1/n$ and $y = x^2$. Then, we have 
$$f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^3}{2x^4} = \dfrac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure how much you know about Riemann integration to conclude from the above. You may point out if any point needs more elaboration.

Comment: Ok so $x=\frac{1}{n}$ is a sequence, right? I am sorry but I am not sure I fully understand that.

Comment: Okay, let me elaborate. I wanted to show that $f$ isn't bounded. One way to do so is to show that $f$ can take arbitrarily large values. So, I've shown that $f(1/n, 1/n^2) = n/2$. Note that $(1/n, 1/n^2) \in [-\pi, \pi]^2$ and that $n/2$ can be made arbitrarily large; that is to say, given any $M\in\Bbb R$, there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n/2 > M$. This shows that $f$ can take arbitrarily large values in the domain.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did a bit of reseasch about this property and now everything is clear.

Comment: Great. One more thing I'd point out: Depending on your definition of Riemann integration, requiring $f$ to be bounded can either be an a priori requirement or something that is a consequence of your definition. If you've studied it via tagged partitions, then it is a result of the definition. However, if you've studied it via upper and lower sums, then the definition requires $f$ to be bounded, to begin with.